# How to pluralize generated controllers in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have generated a few controllers using `rails generate controller` and I forgot about pluralizing them.

Now I have written code all over the views and controllers. Is there any way to fix this quickly?

Comment: I would do it manually.  `grep` is your friend.

Comment: I would follow the advise of @steveklein. `grep -r 'controller_name' ./app/*`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any automated way to change these, especially once you've added code to them.

If you hadn't added code, you could have done:

`rails destroy controller thing && rails generate controller things`

As a side note, for brevity you can use aliases of `destroy` and `generate` in that command so it would become:

`rails d controller thing && rails g controller things`